# How to display text vertically on a button in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a button and display it's text vertically on it, in JavaFX. I am aware of rotate but I do not want to use it.Is there any other way to name the button vertically.[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve this issue but you can display text top down by setting multi line on the button's text field in scene builder. Or by setting newlines in the text string. "E\nX\nA\nM\nP\nL\nE"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rotate is the way to do this, there is no other solution.

[image: rotated]

Sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/* Displays a button with it's text rotated 90 degrees to the left */
public class RotatedText extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button feedbackButton = createButtonWithRotatedText("Feedback Form");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().setAll(feedbackButton);
        StackPane.setAlignment(feedbackButton, Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
        layout.setPrefSize(225, 275);
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightcyan;");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Button createButtonWithRotatedText(String text) {
        Button button = new Button();
        Label  label  = new Label(text);
        label.setRotate(-90);
        button.setGraphic(new Group(label));

        // in-line css just used for sample purposes,
        // usually you would apply a stylesheet.
        button.setStyle(
                "-fx-base: orange; " +
                "-fx-font-size: 30px; " +
                "-fx-text-background-color: whitesmoke;"
        );

        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `button.setGraphic(new Group(label))`  over `button.setGraphic(label)` ?

Comment: Try it and see C0der.  If you wrap it in a group, you get the desired result.  If you don't wrap it in a group you'll get a garbled mess.  This is because of how layout works for a [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) (which differs from other node types): "if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds".